# Do you want the electronics questions from Stack Overflow to be moved to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I have created a question on Meta Stack Overflow to request blacklisting of our favorite tags like fpga, analog-to-digital-converter, asic etc. on Stack Overflow so that questions on those topics would be asked here, where they rightfully belong. Then we won't have to look at *two* Stack Exchange sites for questions and answers.

[question deleted]https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405365/should-not-stack-overflow-be-exclusively-for-programming-questions

What do you think?

Edit: The question I asked on Meta Stack Overflow got deleted and unfortunately I did not take a screenshot of it or archive it or print it.

Comment: Always happy to help, [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqA1m.jpg), and here are the links to my queries as shown in my answer: [questions per tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1375545),  [# questions asked per week](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1375547#graph)

Comment: @rene, thank you. Please let this comment be for future reference.

Comment: visit [this link for your deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/12311164), click each link found there and then follow the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/955763/screenshot-of-a-scrollable-page-in-chrome) to get the screenshots. Good luck!

Comment: It was a bit harsh that they closed the question. It was a valid question even though unpopular. Oddly though, it was mostly PC programmers who had an opinion. It would be much more interesting and valid to hear what those actually participating in HDL Q&A there think, and why they can't do that here instead.

Comment: Also see: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7367/238188

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, embedded systems programming has always been on-topic at SO. It's a scope overlap with this site. As one of the few who actively user-moderate the embedded tag there, I believe this was a big mistake.

Because embedded systems questions - particularly trouble-shooting ones - could either be about software or hardware. And as soon as you discover that your problem is in hardware, the question suddenly turns off-topic. Very awkward situation. Those questions would be in a much better place on this site. And then of course on SO you always get the occasional clueless PC programmer showing up to answer embedded systems questions, with post quality ranging from mildly useless to blatantly incorrect.

And then of course we have the random clueless people who ask pure electronics hardware questions on SO thinking it is ok somehow. Because of this I recently pushed to have [the electronics tag purged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404730/the-electronics-are-all-burninated) and the community agreed. So that should hopefully be a little bit of on-topic traffic coming this way instead.

But it's too late to fix SO now, it is what it is - embedded systems questions are on-topic there, including microcontroller programming and HDL languages. And therefore that site needs ADC, FPGA, ASIC etc tags too. At any rate, such things should be discussed at SO.

I think it takes a new site to fix this: when we launched the software development & electrical engineering communities at [Codidact](https://codidact.com/), I insisted to keep embedded systems on the software site and have those asked at the EE site instead, with no scope overlap. Though if that separation of topics will work out better is too early to tell, since the site is still young. If it works well, then that's evidence that SE could benefit from the same - time will tell.

Answer (score 4):

Overlap is allowed. Tags are only for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Stack overflow thinks that they should be able to write software questions about fpga's adcs ect.

1. They should be able to manage their own tags
2. These tags are fine on that site
3. I am also under the opinion that those tags are fine on SO
4. Question migration takes care of this problem. If there are new questions that are off topic on one site and on topic on another, they can be migrated (ask a moderator, and have a good reason and check on topicness before requesting a migration)
5. Asking for votes is inappropriate in most cases (the asking was edited from the OP)

Comment: Just in case this gets done, and someone has a badge in Verilog on SO, will that get transferred to EE.SE?

Comment: I have edited my question. I am not asking for upvotes. But I would like to know *your* perspective on this.

Comment: I gave my perspective in the answer above, badges do not transfer, also questions older than 1 month cannot be transferred and should not be. If you really want to look in to why and how these decisions are being made, they are site wide (meaning all the sites) and are discussed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/ Before posting on *the meta* site, make sure you do proper research and have a good understanding of every aspect of an issue. People really don't like questions posted on a whim with no research there.

Comment: That question I asked on Meta Overflow got deleted by moderators. Do you think you can delete this one too?

Comment: I spent time on this, so I don't want it to be wasted, there are still educational things people can learn from looking at this.

Comment: "They should be able to manage their own tags" don't you know that several sites have spawned because SO is incapable of managing their sites? Code golf, software recommendations, software engineering, game dev, super user, server fault and I think tex.se too. Claiming that SO is capable of managing anything at its size is a stretch.

Comment: @Braiam Capability is not the question, they have the ability and that is all that is needed for this discussion

Comment: Ability to do what exactly, if they have no capability?