# Does Digital Design fall into our realm or Stack Overflows realm?

Tags: discussion, support

Lots of digital electronics, FPGA Design, Register Transfer Level (RTL) Design questions have been asked and **continue to be asked** on Stack Overflow, a site for programmers.

Take a look at this one, for instance: [Two ways to write pipelines in Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61791834/12311164). It was asked in 2020. This question is a very good fit for Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange. Currently there are many good questions related to EE topics which get asked there and some are closed since they have no code. See this one: [Latches are transparent to half of the clock cycle. Means?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56198758/12311164) One long time Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange user who also uses Stack Overflow has written in a comment on the question:

> It is perfectly clear to me what he is asking. However the question should have been on the electronics exchange

This problem is because some users claim FPGA Programming and RTL Design is programming since an HDL looks a little like a programming language.

This issue has been raised on Meta Stack Overflow 3 years back: [Is digital design on-topic without HDL code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354015/12311164)

### The [right answer by user Tropical_Peach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354155/12311164) to the above question is now getting downvoted and might get deleted soon.

This issue was not fixed and has now grown bigger.

I am posting it here since it is very relevant to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.

I would like to know the opinion of the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange Community on this question. The problem is if good digital design, FPGA programming questions continue to go there, we won't get them here. Some users participate on both Stack Overflow and Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange, since they are interested in these topics. However, many who are interested in these topics remain only on Stack Overflow.

We have to recognise that there are experts on every Stack Exchange site, and these sites flourish because of the experts.

Which site should experts in FPGA, RTL design, digital design and related fields use?

Ideally, the answer should be Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange alone. If the answer is both Stack Overflow and Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange, then there is a possibility that experts in these topics would be divided into 2 sites. This has already happened.

One user has mentioned overlap is allowed. But I don't think overlap is always a good thing. Stack Overflow should be for programming questions, and Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange should be for Electronics design questions, as their respective tours state.

If someone has a question related to these topics should they ask on Stack Overflow or Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange?

Comment: I agree this site should include diversity from the analog issues, but better answers may be supported elsewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please look in the help center to learn how this site works, and please do research before posting (it is wasting my time and others to post on issues that could be worked out by learning how the site works):
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help

This would be of value for you to read:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote

The answer that was posted on SO is off topic and it is also a comment, which is why it received downvotes.

Voting is a way to flag and remove bad content, and a way to get feedback. It is a tool. if it were a mod on that site, I would have that content deleted because it is not useful and half of the post should have been comments (answers should almost always not have discussion in them, that is what the comment system is for). Normally answers are not deleted but that one does not follow the guidelines. When posts get downvoted, usually its because there is improper use of the site.

Secondly we don't concern ourselves here with things that are happening on SO, so please **don't** post about problems on SO on this meta, no one here can do anything for problems there.

Any future meta posts regarding SO on this meta will be deleted. I'll leave this one for educational purposes.

Comment: Which answer? You mean the one by Tropical_Peach?

Comment: That would be the one

Comment: That answer was posted on Meta SO, not SO.

Comment: That is what I mean by SO, if there is a problem there, it needs to be taken care of there. The sites are like containers

Comment: That is an answer, not a comment. The question has the "discussion" tag after all.

Comment: I can understand your point. But I disagree that this has *nothing* to do with Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange and cannot be discussed on this Meta. There is no such rule that I could find.

Comment: Again, half of the answer is referencing others posts which means half of the answer should have been put into comments. Others did not like the post so it was downvoted

Comment: Most people here don't even participate on SO, so what do you want people to do? They have no rep on that site and can't even vote over on the SO meta. The mod's here have no way to fix issues on SO or the Meta, and we are not familiar with the community or rules. It would be very difficult for us to have any influence over there.

Comment: "If someone has a question related to these topics should they ask on Stack Overflow or **Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange?**" - This question is relevant to this site. You have not written anything in your answer that is relevant to my question.

Comment: The meta here is for posting topics that are relevant to the EE.SE community: See here: ...Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other about Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)
...Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange users to communicate with Stack Overflow the company (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new features), and

Comment: That came from this link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354015/is-digital-design-on-topic-without-hdl-code/354155#354155

Comment: Again I welcome your participation on the site, but please read in the help center before posting to learn the issues and how the sites work all the information is there. The second place to look is the meta to see how issues are handled.

Comment: To be abundantly clear, we will not be deleting Tropical_Peach's answer (regardless of what the question OP here might think), though it'll probably be downvoted heavily now that the situation has gotten a lot of attention, and more people are agreeing with the general statement that certain EE bits are on-topic on SO. Mentioning this here to prevent a misrepresentation of the situation.

Comment: @Zoe, I never said you had too, I said I would if given the chance (so I don't know why you'd even mention that but whatever), Do you moderate SO?